# Pandasql with conditions

Tags: python, sql, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes:

- First one i have student information. I will call it df1

  ```
  user_id  | plan      | subplan | matrix_code | student_semester 
  102532   | GADMSSP   | GSP10   | 1501        | 8
  106040   | GRINTSP   |         | 1901        | 4
  106114   | GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 4
  106504   | GCSOSSP   |         | 1902        | 3
  106664   | GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 4
  ```
- Second one I have the requirements of electives for an institution. I will call it df2.

  ```
  plan      | subplan | matrix_code | semester  | credits| cumulative_credits

  GADMSSP   |         | 1501        | 5         | 4      | 4 
  GADMSSP   |         | 1501        | 6         | 4      | 8
  GADMSSP   |         | 1501        | 7         | 4      | 12 
  GADMSSP   |         | 1501        | 8         | 0      | 12

  GRINTSP   |         | 1901        | 7         | 2      | 2
  GRINTSP   |         | 1901        | 8         | 0      | 2

  GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 3         | 4      | 4
  GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 4         | 0      | 4
  GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 5         | 0      | 4
  GCSOSSULA | GSUL5   | 1901        | 5         | 4      | 8
  GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 6         | 0      | 4
  GCSOSSULA | GSUL5   | 1901        | 6         | 0      | 8
  GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 7         | 0      | 4
  GCSOSSULA | GSUL5   | 1901        | 7         | 0      | 8
  GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 8         | 0      | 4
  GCSOSSULA | GSUL5   | 1901        | 8         | 0      | 8

  GCSOSSP   |         | 1902        | 5         | 4      | 4
  GCSOSSP   |         | 1902        | 6         | 4      | 8
  GCSOSSP   |         | 1902        | 7         | 4      | 12
  GCSOSSP   |         | 1902        | 8         | 0      | 12

  GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 2         | 4      | 4
  GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 3         | 4      | 8
  GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 4         | 4      | 12
  GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 5         | 4      | 16
  GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 6         | 4      | 24
  GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 7         | 4      | 32
  GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 8         | 4      | 40
  ```

So i have to merge the df considering some conditions:

1. `plan` and `matrix_code` must be the same for df1 and df2.
2. `df1.subplan` is either the same of `df2.subplan` or it can be null. So user_id 102532 in line 1 of df1 will get the requirements of `df2.subplan` null, since there is no indication of specific `subplan` requirements for this plan and `matrix_code`.
3. Get `student_semester +1`, but considering max `df2.semester` as the limit of `student_semester`. So user_id 102532 in line 1 must remain in semester 8. This one I cannot add +1 semester, but i would like to indicate that it is a user that did not reach the requirements in the last semester.
4. I am only interested in cumulative_credits.

For this two dfs the result should be something like this:

```
user_id  | plan      | subplan | matrix_code | semester | student_semester | cumulative_credits
102532   | GADMSSP   | GSP10   | 1501        | 8        | 9                | 12               
106040   | GRINTSP   |         | 1901        | 5        | 4                | 0
106114   | GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 5        | 4                | 4
106504   | GCSOSSP   |         | 1902        | 4        | 3                | 0
106664   | GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 5        | 4                | 16
```

But if there is no possible way to get the students with 0 cumulative_credits, the result should be:

```
user_id  | plan      | subplan | matrix_code | semester | student_semester | cumulative_credits
102532   | GADMSSP   | GSP10   | 1501        | 8        | 9                | 12               
106114   | GCSOSSULA |         | 1901        | 5        | 4                | 4
106664   | GCINESP   |         | 1901        | 5        | 4                | 16
```

What i did untill now is the following:

```
pip install -U pandasql

import pandas as pd
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())


df2 = df2.groupby(['plan', 'subplan', 'matrix_code', 'semester']).cumulative_credits.max()
df2 = df2.to_frame()
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

```
electives = """ 
SELECT user_id
  ,a.plan
  ,a.subplan as "student_subplan"
  ,a.matrix_code
  ,a.student_semester
  ,b.subplan as "matrix_subplan"
  ,b.semester
  ,cumulative_credits
FROM df1 a
LEFT JOIN df2 b 
ON a.plan = b.plan
AND a.matrix_code = b.matrix_code
WHERE (b.subplan = '' OR a.subplan = b.subplan)
""" 
electives = pysqldf(electives)
```

Then i was trying to get the 3rd condition, but I have no clue in the right way to do this. I think i could use a lambda but I am not sure how.

```
df_s['semester_x'] = df_s['student_semester'] +1 | df_s['student_semester'] == df_s['semester'].max()
```

Also, if there is a better way to do the previous conditions steps using a merge with a condition, it could be nice.

**EDIT - SOLUTION:**

I used part of Parfait's solution. I just made a conditional logic to get the cumulative credits of student next semester instead of max cumulative credits of matrix code.

Here is what I've done:

**First part - Parfait's solution:**

```
agg = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['plano', 'matriz'], suffixes=["", "_"])
         .fillna('')
         .query("(subplano == '') | (subplano_aluno == subplano)")
         .rename({'subplano':'subplano_matriz', 'semestre_': 'semestre_matriz', 'semestre': 'semestre_aluno'}, axis='columns')
```

**Second part:**

```
y = """
with a as 
(
SELECT DISTINCT plan
  ,CASE 
        WHEN plan LIKE '%SULB%' OR plano LIKE '%SULC%' THEN 10
        WHEN plan LIKE '%SULD%' OR plano LIKE '%SULE%' THEN 12
        ELSE 8
      END as "semester_max"
FROM agg
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
  user_id
  ,student_semester
  ,plan
  ,student_subplan
  ,matrix_code
  ,matrix_subplan
  ,cumulative_credits
  ,matrix_semester
  ,semester_max
  ,CASE 
      WHEN student_semester < semester_max THEN (student_semester)+1
      WHEN student_semester = semester_max THEN student_semester
  END as "next_semester"
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      user_id
      ,student_semester
      ,b.plan
      ,student_subplan
      ,matrix_code
      ,matrix_subplan
      ,cumulative_credits
      ,matrix_semester
      ,semester_max
    FROM agg b
    INNER JOIN a ON b.plano = a.plano
) x
WHERE matrix_semester = next_semester
"""
z = pysqldf(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding a `CASE` statement in SQL query:

```sql
SELECT d1.user_id
       , d1.plan
       , d1.subplan AS student_subplan
       , d1.matrix_code
       , d1.student_semester
       , d2.subplan AS matrix_subplan
       , CASE 
             WHEN d1.student_semester = MAX(d2.semester)
             THEN d1.student_semester
             ELSE d1.student_semester + 1
         END AS semester
       , MAX(d2.cumulative_credits) AS cumulative_credits
FROM df1 d1
LEFT JOIN df2 d2 
   ON d1.plan = d2.plan
   AND d1.matrix_code = d2.matrix_code
WHERE (d2.subplan IS NULL OR d1.subplan = d2.subplan)
GROUP BY d1.user_id
       , d1.plan
       , d1.subplan
       , d1.matrix_code
       , d1.student_semester
       , d2.subplan;
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10b5e/1)</kbd>

In Pandas, translation would use `merge` + `groupby` + `Series.where` for case conditional logic:

```py
# MERGE
agg = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['plan', 'matrix_code'], suffixes=["", "_"])
         .fillna('')
         .query("(subplan_ == '') | (subplan == subplan_)")
         .rename({'subplan':'student_subplan', 'subplan_':'matrix_subplan'}, axis='columns')
      )

# AGGRGEATION
agg = (agg.groupby(['user_id', 'plan', 'student_subplan', 'matrix_code', 
                    'student_semester', 'matrix_subplan'], as_index=False)
          .agg({'semester':'max', 'cumulative_credits':'max'})
      )

# CONDITIONAL LOGIC
agg['semester'] = agg['student_semester'].where(agg['semester'] == agg['student_semester'], 
                                                agg['student_semester'].add(1))

agg
#    user_id       plan student_subplan  matrix_code  student_semester matrix_subplan  semester  cumulative_credits
# 0   102532    GADMSSP           GSP10         1501                 8                        8                  12
# 1   106040    GRINTSP                         1901                 4                        5                   2
# 2   106114  GCSOSSULA                         1901                 4                        5                   4
# 3   106504    GCSOSSP                         1902                 3                        4                  12
# 4   106664    GCINESP                         1901                 4                        5                  40
```

Comment: The only thing that didn't work was the cumulative_credits. I need to get the cumulative_credits until student_semester +1 to know the limit of credits they have for that semester

Comment: Would this [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10b5e/10) work where you join again? However, one user shows up twice.

Comment: (Let's delete previous above comments) For that dupe record both are at same plan / matrix_code / semester+1 but different cumulative credits. Your desired results wants the lesser cumulative credits value. Not sure if this is a pandas/sql course problem or actual work problem but need to think about your overall needs. Only you determine correct output. Try playing around with query. Maybe clean source data of such dupe matches?

Comment: What I need is the cumulative credits of student next semester (so if he is now in 6th, i wanna get 7th semester requirements of cumulative credits. But if he is in last semester right now, I have to track if he did complete all the credits he needed (so if he is now in 8th, i should list the 8th semester requirements to check if he completed it or not)

Comment: Consider a second join and aggregation with updated [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10b5e/23/0).

Comment: i got the result with SQL. Posted here. But used the first part - merge - of your solution. It also helped to understand how I can do the conditional logic using pandas. Thank you

Comment: Excellent! Great to hear and glad to help. Happy coding!